# Looking for a good WebDAV enabled windows editor

Tags: windows, editor

Within our company we use a proprietary template engine, which stores its templates in a MySQL database. We recently developed a WebDAV interface for this, which allows us to use standard tools to edit them, instead of a nasty `<textarea>`.

The standard operating-system webdav clients aren't great though, so for OS/X we went with Coda, which has amazing WebDAV support and saves us a ton of time.

Some of our devs are on Windows though, is anyone aware of a good editor that comes with built-in WebDAV support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [Netdrive](http://www.netdrive.net/). Even though it has it's own share of problems (bad, bad multi-user support) the client behaves a lot smoother than Windows' and does a lot of built-in caching.

Upvoted both other answers for helpfulness

Answer (score 3):

You can [mount the WebDAV URI as a local drive](http://web.archive.org/web/20081220082700/https://www.hss.caltech.edu/help/web/webdav/accessing/windowsxp) and then access it using a standard editor, like notepad.exe or slightly fancier ones such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm).

Comment: The problem with the built-in windows client, is that it makes a lot of unneeded request for files it won't actually need. This makes the experience very slow. 

OS/X finder was even worse, which is why Coda is so much better (because it's not a standard mount, it just does exactly the request it needs to).

Comment: Hm?

As far as I can tell, it doesn't actually *download* the files unless you try and open them.

Comment: It does a lot more though, windows will check for updates of the files, scan directories excessively, etc. It's difficult to use over a slow connection mainly, just like how the FTP mounting experience is windows is sub-par.

Comment: There also appear to be other utilities you can use detailed on http://plone.org/documentation/how-to/webdav , but they seem to cost money.

Comment: While not a great question, an even less good answer (link is no longer functioning)

Comment: Er, excuse me? There are real humans here.

Comment: The broken link has been repaired. (FYI: nearly all users can ‘edit’ answers on StackExchange Network sites to fix broken links, make questions better / more clear, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) XML editor can [use WebDAV](http://www.oxygenxml.com/ftp_webdav.html). It might be worth checking if one can edit non XML files with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a good FTP client (such as [CrossFTP](http://www.crossftp.com) that handles SFTP, WebDav, and Amazon S3 protocols) to edit your remote files with your favorite editor.

Answer (score 1):

There are [Bluefish](http://www.bennewitz.com/bluefish/stable/binaries/win32/), [gedit](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gedit/), [Kate](http://windows.kde.org/download.php) etc. They are primarily built for Linux but Windows ports are available in the links I have posted. They are all full blown editors too as you would hardly miss a feature. For questions like this the best source to have a primary lookup is [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Expression Web 4 is actually a good fit for this.  As of December 2012 it is now [free](http://web.archive.org/web/20170514074919/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36179) *(as in beer)* but [unsupported](http://web.archive.org/web/20170610051355/http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/) *(as in development has ceased)*.

I use it to edit HTML and CSS files and publish to my host via WebDAV.  It does everything you would expect, syntax-highlighting, auto-complete, syncing changes and probably much more.

I am not terribly bothered by the fact that it is abandonware, it definitely is the best fit for my needs right now. [More info on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Web)